# Framework constructor

Tags: javascript, constructor, framework

I'm working on my framework constructor. First I tried to look into jQuery and understand it, but it's so out of my league. Instead I googled and put this code together. Though there aren't many posts about creating a framework. Anyway, since I'm not a guru I might be doing it the wrong way or missing things. Can I take your opinions, suggestions to make it a little more stable?

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/dXTy4/)

```
var optionalSelector = "$";

(function () {
    (this[arguments[0]] = function constructor(input) {
        if (!(this instanceof constructor)) {
            return new constructor(input);
        }

        var regExp_id = /^#/;
        var regExp_class = /^\./;
        var regExp_tag = /[^#]|[^.]/;

        var typeOfInput;

        function isElement(obj) {
            if (obj !== null && typeof obj === "object") {
                return obj;
            }
        }

        if (isElement(input)) {
            return input;
        } // this
        else {
            if (input.search(regExp_id) != -1) {
                typeOfInput = "id";
            } else if (input.search(regExp_class) != -1) {
                typeOfInput = "class";
            } else if (input.search(regExp_tag) != -1) {
                typeOfInput = "tag";
            }

            switch (typeOfInput) {

                case "id":
                    if (document.getElementById(input.replace(/#/, ""))) {
                        return document.getElementById(input.replace(/#/, ""));
                    } else {
                        console.log("Invalid id: " + input);
                        return false;
                    }
                    break;

                case "class":
                    if (document.getElementsByClassName(input.replace(/./, "")).length > 0) {
                        return document.getElementsByClassName(input.replace(/./, ""));
                    } else {
                        console.log("Invalid class: " + input);
                        return false;
                    }
                    break;

                case "tag":
                    if (document.getElementsByTagName(input).length > 0) {
                        return document.getElementsByTagName(input);
                    } else {
                        console.log("Invalid tag: " + input);
                        return false;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    })
})(optionalSelector);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, nice effort for the code. But I highly go against it because there's [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). And if you don't like jQuery because it's heavy, then I suggest going for [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/).

But anyways, back to your code. First I notice this one:

```
var optionalSelector = "$";
```

Never use `$`. It's being abused already by frameworks. Use another namespace to avoid collisions with mainstream libraries, something unique, like `MyVeryAmazingDomLibrary` or `MVADL` for short. Hehehe.

Also, I notice this namespace declaration happens to be outside the library. Do include it inside the library's module:

```
;(function(window){
  ...
  window.myNamespace = myLibraryStuffHere;
  ...
}(window));
```

So far, your code looks ok. Everything is pretty much covered. I also see that it works only with single selectors at the moment. However, I notice you are using `replace` to remove the `#` and `.`:

```
document.getElementById(input.replace(/#/, ""));
```

RegExp is heavy for trivial operations such as this. You can remove the *first character* using `substr` or `substring`. That way, you avoid RegExp.

```
document.getElementById(input.substr(1));
```

Now, in the demo, I see this:

```
a[0].onclick = function() { alert("you clicked the classes"); }
a[1].onclick = function() { alert("you clicked the classes"); }
```

If you had a hundred elements, would you do this still? I assume you'd do a loop, right? But wouldn't it be neat if the library took care of that? Yes?

So there's a reason they call it a "jQuery object". jQuery objects are basically arrays (array-like to be exact, normally called a set or collection) that applies operations to each item in the collection.

So to get you on the right track, think of this code:

```
a.on('click',someFunction);
```

`a` is the jQuery object, and `on` is a method of jQuery that attaches a `click` handler to each item in set `a`. `on` would look like:

```
myAmazingLibraryObject.prototype.on = function(event,handler){

  //assuming "this" represents the current collection and "elements"
  //is an array of elements, a result of getting by tag or by class.
  //Let's say we are standards compliant and ES5 compliant, 
  //we use forEach to loop through the set, and addEventListener to 
  //add the handlers.

  this.elements.forEach(function(element){
    element.addEventListener(event,handler,false);
  });
}
```

Now, you can do this:

```
var elements = myAmazingLibrary('a'); //get all <a>

elements.on('click',function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('clicked');
});
```

An advantage of using a jQuery-like object, where the results are contained in an array, is that even when your collection is empty, the code does not break. If we used `on` on an empty collection, nothing will go wrong. Empty set, no loop, no element access, no error.

Lastly, don't just `console.log` or return false on errors. Throw meaningful errors instead. Use `Error` objects so that `try-catch` can collect them and inspect them. The last thing you would want from your code is to have it running broken and not know about it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'm not coding for living, but for fun. That's why I try to avoid using libraries. With libraries work gets done but you don't know what's going on. I wanted to create my own framework to practise and get a better understanding. Last state of [the code](http://jsfiddle.net/dXTy4/2/). Also will add the `try-catch` method. Oh, and about handling arrays. Of course I'd use a loop. I have methods for these :)